# i am using regex function but it didn't work?

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex, match

When i use regex function for title and caption then it works
but when I add more matching tags then it not works

here is the code below **which works fine** without any problem

```js
  $(".sidebar").each(function() {
        var e = $(this),
            t = e.find(".widget").text();
        if (t) {
            var a = t.match(/title=\(([^)]*)\)\s+caption=\(([^)]*)\)/);
           alert(t);
        }
 });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class='sidebar'>
<div class='widget'>title=(example1) caption=(example2)</div>
</div>
```

But the problem is when I try to use multiple matching tags then it does not works
like

```
<div class='widget'>title=(example1) caption=(example2) button=(example3) price=(example4) off=(example5)</div>
```

I tried hard to use regex same like above for this values but it didn't work

I also want to add these examples text and the Output look like is **example1 example2 example3 example4 example5** but I have no idea done with regex function

any help or advice is highly appreciated

Comment: Regex `/.../g` with g (global) flag to capture one more time

Comment: So you want to match example n inside your string?

Comment: Hi ! And what is your new prerequisite ? The old one or to match existence of `button`, `price` and so on ?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `match()`, consider using `exec()`, which will allow you to access the capture groups as well. Your capture group should ideally capture the value inside the parenthesis coming after the `=` character, so you can write your regex pattern as such:

```
 var re = /\w+?=\((.*?)\)/gi;
```

Then, it is simply a matter of running a `while` loop to recursively invoke the `exec()` method until no more matches can be found:

```js
$(".sidebar").each(function() {
  var e = $(this);
  var t = e.find(".widget").text();

  if (t) {
    var result;
    var results = [];
    var re = /\w+?=\((.*?)\)/gi;
    while ((result = re.exec(t)) !== null) {
      console.log(result[1]);
      results.push(result[1]);
    }
    
    console.log('Logging all captured values:\n', results);
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class='sidebar'>
  <div class='widget'>title=(example1) caption=(example2) button=(example3) price=(example4) off=(example5)</div>
</div>
```

Even better: you don't even need jQuery for this:

```js
document.querySelectorAll('.sidebar .widget').forEach(el => {
  const t = el.innerText.trim();
  
  if (t) {
    let result;
    const results = [];
    const re = /\w+?=\((.*?)\)/gi;
    while ((result = re.exec(t)) !== null) {
      console.log(result[1]);
      results.push(result[1]);
    }
    
    console.log('Logging all captured values:\n', results);
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class='sidebar'>
  <div class='widget'>title=(example1) caption=(example2) button=(example3) price=(example4) off=(example5)</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example on how to get any value given this format:

> **Match anything that is not a `)` one or more times**.
> Must be preceded by `\w+=(`
> and must be followed by `)`

Better explained in [This Regex101 Example](https://regex101.com/r/ftRCAB/1)

```js
$(".sidebar").find(".widget").each(function() {

  const txt = $.trim($(this).text()); // Get trimmed text
  if (!txt) return; // Do nothing
  
  const matches = txt.match(/(?<=\b\w+=\()[^)]+(?=\))/g)||[];
  
  matches.forEach(m => {
    console.log(m);
  });
  
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class='sidebar'>
  <div class='widget'>title=(example1) caption=(example2) button=(example3) price=(example4) off=(example5)</div>
  <div class="widget">ola</div>
  <div class="widget"></div>
  <div class="widget">The magic happens=(here) :)</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

In your code, you use `alert(t);` which is the result from `t = e.find(".widget").text();`

If you use the result from `var a = t.match(/title=\(([^)]*)\)\s+caption=\(([^)]*)\)/);` then the regex will return a match for `title=` and `caption=` which either have a value in a capture group, but the match should be in that order.

You will get a single match as there is no `/g` flag, and there is also only 1 occurrence in the example data.

What you could do is make your expression a bit less restrictive, and instead of matching specifically on title and capture, match 1 or more non whitespace characters other than an equals sign instead.

Use the `/g` flag to get all the matches instead of a single match.

```
[^\s=]+=\(([^)]*)\)
```

- `[^\s=]+` Match 1+ times any char other than `=` or a whitespace char
- `=` Match literally
- `\(` Match `(`
- `([^)]*)` Capture in **group 1** optional characters other than `)` or use `+` instead of `*` for 1 or more
- `\)` Match `)`

A [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/YpD7b1/1) to see the captured group values:

```js
$(".sidebar").each(function() {
  var e = $(this),
    t = e.find(".widget").text();
  if (t) {
    var a = t.matchAll(/[^\s=]+=\(([^)]*)\)/g);
    console.log(Array.from(a, m => m[1]));
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class='sidebar'>
  <div class='widget'>title=(example1) caption=(example2) button=(example3) price=(example4) off=(example5)</div>
</div>
```